# Send email from localhost running XAMMP in PHP using GMAIL mail server

Tags: php, email, gmail, sendmail.exe

I try to send an email from localhost to my yahoo email account using php mail() function, the return says I successfully send the email but I did not get any email. I've been reading and trying many so called 'simple way' to send email but the result are disappointing, none of them work for me. Below are the code, the configurations and the error message. Can someone enlighten me with this? Thanks.

php code

```
<?php
$to      = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Fake sendmail test';
$message = 'If we can read this, it means that our fake Sendmail setup works!';
$headers = 'From: myemail@egmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
    die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
}
?>
```

Configuration for php.ini (I'm using gmail mail server)

> SMTP =smtp.gmail.com
>   smtp_port =587
>   sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
>   sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Configuration for sendmail.ini

> smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
>   smtp_port=587
>   smtp_ssl=tls
>   error_logfile=error.log
>   debug_logfile=debug.log
>   auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
>   auth_password=mypassword
>   force_sender=myemail@gmail.com

error message in sendmail error log with port 587

> 13/10/02 13:36:41 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k4sm129639pbd.11 - gsmtp

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/O1zw89

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here's](http://byitcurious.blogspot.com/2009/04/solving-must-issue-starttls-command.html) the link that gives me the answer:

> [Install] the "[fake sendmail for windows](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/)". If you are not using XAMPP you can download it here: http://glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip
>
> ```
> [Modify] the php.ini file to use it (commented out the other lines):
>
> [mail function]
> ; For Win32 only.
> ; SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
> ; smtp_port = 25
>
> ; For Win32 only.
> ; sendmail_from = <e-mail username>@gmail.com
>
> ; For Unix only. You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
> sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
> ```

(ignore the "Unix only" bit, since we actually are using sendmail)

> You then have to configure the "sendmail.ini" file in the directory where sendmail was installed:
>
> ```
> [sendmail]
>
> smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
> smtp_port=25
> error_logfile=error.log
> debug_logfile=debug.log
> auth_username=<username>
> auth_password=<password>
> force_sender=<e-mail username>@gmail.com
> ```

To access a Gmail account protected by 2-factor verification, you will need to create an [application-specific password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords). ([source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45341/115031))

Comment: I think gmail now requires ssl

Comment: I have been searching for this config details about 2 days, thanks man, this post really helped me to solve problem :).

Comment: For quick testing in localhost, the gmail account being used in auth_username should have setting to allow access for low secure apps from here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

in php.ini file,uncomment this one

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

and in sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=your@gmail.com
auth_password=yourpassword
force_sender=your@gmail.com
hostname=localhost
```

configure this one..it will works...it working fine for me.

thanks.

Comment: It worked for me. I just had to configure my Gmail account to "Allow less secure apps: ON". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com  
smtp_port=25  
error_logfile=error.log  
debug_logfile=debug.log  
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com 
auth_password=gmailpassword  
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

need authenticate username and password of mail then only once can successfully send mail from localhost

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to generate a second password for your Gmail account.
You will use this new password in your code. Read this:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Under the section "How to generate an App password" click on "App passwords", then under "Select app" choose "Mail", select your device and click "Generate". Your second password will be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use PHPMailer and Gmail SMTP. The configuration would be like the below.

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                            
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';            
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
$mail->Username = 'Email Address';          
$mail->Password = 'Email Account Password'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';               
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Example script and full source code can be found from here - [How to Send Email from Localhost in PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-in-php/)