# Setting up email with wamp

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp

I have seen so many website templates that have an AJAX based contact form and when you click on submit to send a message they say that it doesnt actually send a mail, 
I will like to implement this system a template that I am building.

I have wamp installed and also the template and php files ready I dont know what to do next.
php file: http://pastebin.com/YGGK7xsH

javascript file: http://pastebin.com/RM2TNFNX

Comment: Change that to `$("#feedbackSubmit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`, furthermore, unless you come with some code that is not working properly or whatever your question is not likely to be answered.

Comment: It's possible to do it on WAMP you just need to input the SMTP information in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use your WAMPP to send the mails because it is a local server.

Look at this post for more information and a solution:
 [Send email from localhost running XAMMP in PHP using GMAIL mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)

Comment: the send mail is a zip file so where should i extract them to?

Answer (score 0):

**Send email from localhost/WAMP Server using sendmail**

This solution requires sendmail.exe (a Command Line Interface (CLI) executable which accepts email from PHP, connects to an SMTP server and sends email). You will not require to use it by command, don’t bother about it :-) [Download the sendmail.zip](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip) and follow these steps:

```
Create a folder named “sendmail” in “C:\wamp\”.
    Extract these 4 files in “sendmail” folder: “sendmail.exe”, “libeay32.dll”, “ssleay32.dll” and “sendmail.ini”.
    Open the “sendmail.ini” file and configure it as following
        smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
        smtp_port=465
        smtp_ssl=ssl
        default_domain=localhost
        error_logfile=error.log
        debug_logfile=debug.log
        auth_username=[your_gmail_account_username]@gmail.com
        auth_password=[your_gmail_account_password]
        pop3_server=
        pop3_username=
        pop3_password=
        force_sender=
        force_recipient=
        hostname=localhost
```

You do not need to specify any value for these properties: pop3_server, pop3_username, pop3_password, force_sender, force_recipient. The error_logfile and debug_logfile settings should be kept blank if you have already sent successful email(s) otherwise size of this file will keep increasing. Enable these log file settings if you don’t get able to send email using sendmail.

**Enable IMAP Access in your GMail’s Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access**

**Enable “ssl_module” module in Apache server**

**Enable “php_openssl” and “php_sockets” extensions for PHP compiler**

Open php.ini from “C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin” and configure it as following 
(The php.ini at “C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.x” would not work) 
(You just need to configure the last line in the following code, prefix semicolon (;) against other lines

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = 
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = you@domain.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

Restart WAMP Server.

Create a PHP file and write the following code in it:

```
<?php
$to       = 'recipient@yahoo.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

Make appropriate changes in $to and $headers variables to set recipient, sender and reply-to address. Save it as “send-mail.php”. (You can save it anywhere or inside any sub-folder in “C:\wamp\www”.)
Open this file in browser, it MUST work now

Ref link http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: Everything is working now but when i check my email, no message is in there. I believe that you guys can help me out. Thank you

Comment: Please check in spam and confirm all the setting in php.ini and httpd.conf file manually.because sometime services shows enabled in wamp but if you open config file then showing not enabled