# Sending email failed using sendmail. STARTTLS issue. using GMail server

Tags: php, email, stunnel, sendmail.exe

I'm trying to send e-mail by local.

I'm using Windows 8.1 , Apache, PHP, Sendmail, Stunnel following [this site](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp)

I aslo followed [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)

But I couldn't send e-mail. Following log is shown.

```
allocated memory  : 8.08 MB
command line      : c:\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t
executable        : sendmail.exe
exec. date/time   : 2011-06-18 01:10
compiled with     : Delphi 2006/07
madExcept version : 3.0l
callstack crc     : $fecf9b34, $97c9b165, $97c9b165
exception number  : 1
exception class   : EIdSMTPReplyError
exception message : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. iq10sm2936159pbc.14 - gsmtp.
```

If anyone have another solution, please let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following link's setting works for me.

http://sathyasays.com/2014/02/23/getting-php-mail-function-running-on-windows-8-1-with-wamp-server-and-configuring-it-to-use-gmails-smtp-servers/