# Email is not being send in PHP

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I am trying to send an email using mail function in `php`. I have read the documentation and followed the examples but in vain. I don't know if I am doing anything wrong.

Can anyone please help me. I also followed other examples from the [community](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) without success.

And here also;
[Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)

Here is my code:

```
$name =array($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['comments']);


    $to = "fasdjgasgd@yahoo.com";
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = "$name[0] wrote the following: <br/> $name[3]";

    $header = "FROM:".$name[1];
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: what error is showing up while you trying to send mail?

Comment: @BlankHead I have not error

Comment: From where are you sending this, from localhost or server?

Comment: is there any mail server installed in your machine?

Comment: @BlankHead I am sure I do not have any email server

Comment: Very nice. :) windows or linux?

Comment: @BlankHead windows 7

Comment: If you're sending this from localhost and have not any mail server, you _can't_ send the email ! Online you should be able to send it, otherwise you need to use some SMTP service from localhost.

Comment: Here is a similar question in stackoverflow that can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server

Comment: @vlzvl which one would be a good SMTP service to use??

Comment: @Alexander, i personally use Gmail SMTP (smtp.gmail.com on port 465, ssl). But note also that SMTP services have _all restrictions_ any may prove slow.

Answer (score 1):

Your server does not have local mailserver.

There are few solutions:

- Install local mail server if you have sufficient rights
- Change your PHP settings to use other mail server (other open mailserver or auth-based ones like Gmail, Yahoo etc)
- Use one of available mail libraries which supports IMAP / POP3 to handle mail sending.
- SwiftMailer or Pear Mail are one of most commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

PHP must be configured correctly in the php.ini file with the details of how your system sends email. Open php.ini file available in /etc/ directory and find the section headed [mail function].

Windows users should ensure that two directives are supplied. The first is called SMTP that defines your email server address. The second is called sendmail_from which defines your own email address.

The configuration for Windows should look something like this:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost

sendmail_from = email@domain.com
```

[This link](http://planetghost.com/send-emails-localhost-xampp-wamp-php) will help you.