# i am not able to send mail using php via localhost

Tags: php, email

I am using ubuntu with xampp. I need to send mail from localhost . I am new to php.Can u help me what are all i need to configure to send mail from localhost?

```
<?php
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "othemail@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) or die("unable to send");
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: have you configured your SMTP? find a tutorial on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

you should try this link to send mail from localhost
 http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/php_send_mail_from_localhost_using_gmail_smtp

which gives you insight about how to send mail from localhost using third party SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You should send email using SMTP, it will work.
It will work in win32. i am not sure about any other.
Check following link.

[Send email from localhost running XAMMP in PHP using GMAIL mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)