# PHP - sending mail using xampp localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp

I'm trying send to a gmail, using xampp.

my **PHP version is 5.6.8**

Using [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) as a guide, 
I changed the config of my php.ini and sendmail.ini But it didn't work for me.
The page always display **Failure: Email was not sent!**

This is my php:

```
$to      = 'kennybanny12@gmail.com';
$subject = 'No subject';
$message = 'Hello, this is the content of the email.';
$headers = 'From: sticollegesocial@gmail.com';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
    die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
}
```

These are the things that I changed in my **php.ini:**

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = sticollegesocial@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini:**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=sticollegesocial@gmail.com
auth_password=**********
force_sender=sticollegesocial@gmail.com
```

Comment: Do you have a SMTP server in your local host??

Comment: And did you download http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you tried well but that post doesn't contain like of an author. [please look into this link](https://www.google.co.in/urlhttps://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server&ved=0CBoQFjAAahUKEwjp25md24PIAhUOcY4KHVghAds&usg=AFQjCNGQbUPpHhDgKKtPSYTuGIs2X4gkzw&sig2=6u81A1qH_B2j6nRHCWOCYA).this might help you.

Comment: What is this URL you put?? Error 404.. @rajesh

Comment: Ohh sorry my mistake .. Click here for correct version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server