# mail function on localhost

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem with php `mail()` function on localhost server.

When we run this on localhost it shows the error :

> "Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and
>   "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\wamp\www\sanyam\l1.php on line 30"

and then shows the message `"Email sent"` when the email was not sent because a warning has occurred

why does it show the message that the email was sent?

Comment: you can not send mail through local server.

Comment: or you can follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server

Comment: i just email is not sent then why show message mail sent when warning occur

Comment: @SantoshPatel It's wrong, you can send email through local server by configure it correctly

Comment: because mail function running successfully but localhost can not send mail.

Comment: @ThomasRollet thats why i mention a url for configuration.