# Bootstrap Contact Form Processing

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Have a Bootstrap contact form coded and working with on exception. When the form is submitted it doesn't tell the user the message was sent. I want when the user sends the data it gets process on the same page with a successful message. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or give me a fix?

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                  <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = '3Form'; 
        $to = 'info@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from 360 Form ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }
        //Check Phone
        if (!$_POST['phone']) {
            $errPhone = 'Please enter a phone Number';
        }
        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! we will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="2 + 3 = ?">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i made a few changes in your code you have to use the isset function in php,  and for the error message you should create it in your CSS file, last thing i removed the authentication because i prefer to write a js/jquery .

                     <body>
               <?php if (!isset($_POST['name'])) { ?>  
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">

       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
    </div>
      </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="2 + 3 = ?">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
        </div>

</div>
                 <?php }
                 else {
                //connect to the db  
                include 'dbconnect.php';  
              //collect the name data 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = '360 Web Fform'; 
        $to = 'info@360websolution.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from 360 Form ';   
           //inserting data to the DB  
             $sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable SET
             YourTable fields....          
             mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
             echo "<span class="error"> Your request will be processed                   shortly</span>";   
                 }  ?>   
                </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                  <?php
$result ='';
$errName='';
$errEmail='';
$errPhone='';
$errMessage='';
$errHuman='';
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = '3Form'; 
        $to = 'info@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from 360 Form ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }
        //Check Phone
        if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
            $errPhone = 'Please enter a phone Number';
        }
        //Check if message has been entered
        if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! we will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="2 + 3 = ?">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <?=$result;?>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

to mailing u need to read here
[Send email from localhost running XAMMP in PHP using GMAIL mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)