# Unable to send mail using XAMPP

Tags: php, email, xampp

I am trying to send email using `localhost` (XAMPP v3.2.1). For that I need to reconfigure `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` file. So far what I have done is, I changed the following in the corresponding files.

In `php.ini` I have changed to :

```
extension=php_openssl.dll (I Remove the semicolon from beginning) 
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And in `sendmail.ini` file I have changed

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

For Testing purpose I have written an `index.php` file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
   </head>

   <body>

      <?php
         $to = "testMailId@gmail.com";
         $subject = "This is subject";

         $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

         $header = "From:senderMailId @gmail.com \r\n";
         $header .= "senderMailId @gmail.com \r\n";
         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $header);

         if($retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         } else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

But the result is showing that message could not be sent. I don’t know if there is any wrong with configuration or code? Please help.

Comment: Here, try this solution from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server refer this too....

Comment: not sure but does there need to be a colon after that Content-type?  `Content-type: text/html;`  I was looking at this line here  `$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'` on php.net and not sure if thats just because two commands on same line, or if necessary.  So check that to make sure.