# laravel 5.4: sending email from localhost not working

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to sent emails from my localhost with laravel 5.4. It is showing me the following error:
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08R2l.jpg)

This is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tfl
```

This is my mail.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

This is my mail class in App\mail\ directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CompanyVerificationEmails extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.comp_ver_emails');
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\General_model;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Session;

use Mail;
use App\Mail\CompanyVerificationEmails;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;


class General_controller extends Controller
{

public function sentemail()
{
     $mail_to = 'receiver_email@gmail.com';

     Mail::to($mail_to)->send(new CompanyVerificationEmails);

     dd('Mail send successfully');
}

}
```

Comment: try changing `smtp` to `mail` as your driver

Comment: in my mail.php file, I have already set the driver to mail

Comment: I believe the ENV file overwrites it. What you have changed is the fallback if no ENV variable exists.

Comment: You need change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` from `tfl` to `tls`

Comment: Hope this article helps in the future for those who are getting the same issue: https://www.scratchcode.io/laravel-send-mail-from-localhost/

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue too, this is how i fixed it. Though it is not advisable to change vendor files but this fix worked and it enable me to send mail from my localhost.

1. Locate StreamBuffer in your vendor folder. It should be in this location

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mylaravel\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport

2. Open the file StreamBuffer.php
3. Find this method _establishSocketConnection
4. Add this as shown below

> $options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
>
> $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;

```
    private function _establishSocketConnection(){
       ....

       $options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
       $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;

       $streamContext = stream_context_create($options);
       $this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    .... }
```

It's like the ssl keeps preventing the mail from been sent. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [log driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#mail-and-local-development) for mail or setting up a mailgun free account but if you really wanna test this from your local dev machine then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server) might help:

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic windows error when trying to send a mail.

Try uncommenting `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of gmail, you can use Mailinator which requires little to no setup and if php returns `true`, Mailinator probably received it. 
https://www.mailinator.com/v4/public/inboxes.jsp