# mail not sending from live server working on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am sending mail from laravel its working fine on localhost but same code is not working on live server following is my mail configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=pranav.bitware@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

i have allowed less secure apps in my account

i don't know why its generating error on **live server**

on some articles they are setting smtp to sendmail i tried that also but getting same error

Comment: Did u see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806610/laravel-5-4-sending-email-from-localhost-not-working
And this -> https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-55-will-not-send-mail-from-localhost-laravel-54-will

Answer (score 1):

Providing the error message you get will help with troubleshooting this issue. Since it works on your localhost, then you should look into the server configuration such as your php and Laravel setup, and firewall settings.