# Want to change from mail id in fake sendmail?

Tags: php, sendmail

I configure my xampp using the following link
[Send email from localhost running XAMMP in PHP using GMAIL mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server)

I want to change from mail dynamically. It took auth-mail as default.

Configuration:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com; 

;smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

smtp_ssl=auto

default_domain=localhost

error_logfile=error.log

auth_username=sanvignesh2015@gmail.com

auth_password=xxxxxxxxxx

pop3_server=

pop3_username=

pop3_password=

force_sender=

force_recipient=
```

And my from mail id is different one.

[image: Refer Following image which i received]

Comment: So you're asking how do you change `sanmailer` to something different?

Comment: no i want to change sanvignesh2015@gmail.com to what i given

Comment: no i leave it as empty

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok thanks, But I am working on this project. That's why i put ASAP and i never use it before.

Comment: So what does your PHP code look like when you're sending mail? Are you including a `From: ` header?

Comment: on header 
$headers .= 'From: <sanmailer18@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

Comment: See [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/o5hlYNQNxmk), for more information. Basically, if you're using gmail for SMTP, you wont be able to do this (Unless you confirm the email as noted in that link).