# send email to specific email id from localhost using xampp

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to send mail to a specific email id from localhost.

I've read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132171/send-email-from-localhost-running-xammp-in-php-using-gmail-mail-server) plus some other posts, but that didn't solve my problem.

Right now I've the following configuration:

**PHP.ini**

```
[mail function]
; *For Win32 only*.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = mypersonal@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**SENDMAIL.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mypersonal@gmail.com
auth_password=my above email password
force_sender=mypersonal@gmail.com
```

**PHP CODE IS **

```
$to = "someFriend@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <mypersonal@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";


$check = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($check == true){
    echo "successfully mail Sent";
}
else{
    echo "Email sending Failed";
}
```

I get `Email sending failed`, is anything wrong with this configuration or code ?
I've also allowed my Gmail to less secure apps

I'm also confused about where to put my own gmail id from where the mails would be sending to others.

Please help !
Thanks

Comment: There are some thing like I mentioned , what to put instead of these or leave them as it is e.g force_sender=<e-mail username>@gmail.com

like the angular brackets etc, should I use my own gmail id ? @Dave

Comment: or please tell me about how can I see my errors if any there, because I don't know where is the problem, the link you've mentioned, I've visited that a number of time before. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, OK! Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Ok,I will.Can you please have a look at the code above, should it work perfectly fine or there is something missing ? @RiggsFolly what do you think ?

Comment: In `sendmail.ini` add `error_logfile=sendmail_error.log` and `debug_logfile=sendmail_debug.log` or have a quick read of [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php)

Comment: Nothing has happened, I added error reporting, still having the previous result

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not allow that by default. Check in your google account settings and allow access to less secure apps. Or generate app specific password and use it here.

Comment: I already done that,mentioned in last part of the question also